# Implementing State Pattern Design in React (Select tool to draw in canvas)

Tags: reactjs

I would like to implement state pattern design in React. The problem is that I want to make list of tool button and when I click to a button the canvas will change behavior (such as click, mouseup, mouse down) follow the tools
but I cannot answer that how to implement on ReactJS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Real world example**

Imagine you are using some drawing application, you choose the paint brush to draw. Now the brush changes it's behavior based on the selected color i.e. if you have chosen red color it will draw in red, if blue then it will be in blue etc.

**In plain words**

It lets you change the behavior of a class when the state changes.

**Programmatic example**

Let's take an example of text editor, it let's you change the state of text that is typed i.e. if you have selected bold, it starts writing in bold, if italic then in italics etc.

First of all we have our transformation functions

```
const upperCase = inputString => inputString.toUpperCase()
const lowerCase = inputString => inputString.toLowerCase()
const defaultTransform = inputString => inputString
```

Then we have our editor

```
class TextEditor {
    constructor(transform) {
        this._transform = transform
    }

    setTransform(transform) {
        this._transform = transform
    }

    type(words) {
        console.log(this._transform(words))
    }
}
```

And then it can be used as

```
const editor = new TextEditor(defaultTransform)

editor.type('First line')

editor.setTransform(upperCase)

editor.type('Second line')
editor.type('Third line')

editor.setTransform(lowerCase)

editor.type('Fourth line')
editor.type('Fifth line')

// Output:
// First line
// SECOND LINE
// THIRD LINE
// fourth line
// fifth line
```

This is a basic example implemented in ES6.This can be used with ReactJs also. Its simple example, But it will give you a good starting point

Comment: thank you so much. it's work well. but I have a little confuse what how to make it auto update with state in react when state change